# How to create a DLL from a C program using Turbo C

Tags: .net, c, assemblies, turbo-c

I wrote a small program in *Turbo C* and I would like to get or create a DLL of this program for using it with my C# application.

So how can I create a DLL of a C program using Turbo C?
I would like to use it with a C# or VB program in a DLL reference.

If found [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106553), but I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Turbo C and compile with Visual C++ since we have to use Win32 calling conventions. Suppose *math.h* is your library.

```
#include <math.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall MyPow(double, double);
}

extern double __stdcall MyPow(double x, double y)
{
    return pow(x, y);
}
```

And then import it in your C# application, using `DllImport`.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]
    extern static double MyPow(double x, double y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyPow(2.0, 5.0));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This makes your code exteremly unmanaged. A Better approach would be creating a Managed C++ wrapper. To do so, create a new Visual C++ Dynamic Library project, enable `Common Language RunTime Support (OldSyntax)` under **Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General** and disable `C++ Exceptions` in **Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation**. Build for release target.

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <math.h>
}

namespace Wrapper
{
    public __gc class MyClass
    {
        public:
            static double MyPow(double x, double y)
            {
                return pow(x, y);
            }
    };
};
```

Then create a new Visual C# project, reference the .DLL file we just made and in **Project Properties > Build**, check `Allow unsafe code` if you're using pointers in your original library and need to modify them in your C# application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Wrapper.MyClass.MyPow(2.0, 5.0));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry bro.. getting run-time error,,!!

Unable to load DLL 'MyLibrary.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

i Tried the first one -
build succeceded for release target in dll and my application couldn't LOAD the DLL..!!?? HElp PLZ..!!

Comment: Sorry bro..!! 
i tried both the win32 project and c# application ran for release target..!!

it worked thanx..!!

Comment: >Yes thanX bro..!! Both works well..

>and what i was lookin for was second type.

>And secound type is really good.

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C (last release in 1989) is a DOS based program. It cannot create Win32 DLLs.

Since you are already using Visual Studio for C#, I would strongly suggest using Visual C++ for your DLL. Visual C++ is self explanatory (hint: Win32 DLL is the project type you want).